# Android Webview goes blank sometimes

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I have a small app that just loads a website using `WebViewClient`

I have observed that on Nexus5 which is running 4.4.4 it just shows a blank screen even when there is a good network.

This is very rare , but I need to find out the reason why it happens. The app components apart from the `WebViewClient` is  responsive during this time.

Any pointers much appreciated

I implemented a class that extends `WebViewClient`

I have overloaded the following functions

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

@Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

 @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code was the webView object that was used was getting edited in other place since it was a static variable. My Bad, that was complete disaster to use this object as static. Once I converted to instance variable, it worked.